# Short story about astronaut who finds God’s experiment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, astronauts

I read this story in the late 60s/early 70s.

It’s about a lone astronaut who lands on a planet (I think) and sees plants, like in a garden but each plant is minutely different than the ones around it.

Then he stumbles upon a workshop/lab and some sort of written record that he deciphers, which tells him that human beings are a failed experiment due to be terminated by the owner of the lab, which I assumed to be God or some kind of supreme being.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

["Hobbyist"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41311) (Eric Frank Russell, 1947) is a close match, except that the notes describe humanity as "moderately successful".

You can read the [full story](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v40n01_1947-09_cape1736#page/n31/mode/2up) at the Internet Archive.

See also: [Need to identitify a short story about an astronaut stranded alone on a planet that houses a strange museum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153721/need-to-identitify-a-short-story-about-an-astronaut-stranded-alone-on-a-planet-t)

Comment: That story REALLY reminds me of Terry Pratchett's The Last Continent, I wonder if he had read it?

Comment: @Whelkaholism, that crossed with [Haldane](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/J._B._S._Haldane)'s line about the creator having `an inordinate fondness for beetles`

Comment: Yes, it is "Hobbyist." Thank you for solving the mystery for me.