# Lone space pilot searching for habitable planets with a mynah bird his only companion

Tags: story-identification

While traveling between potential stellar systems, a pilot stumbles across a habitable planet that shouldn't be there. He lands and starts to explore. All the flora is separate from its neighbours with no overlap. Eventually, a building appears in the distance and he realizes as he gets nearer that it is massive. He finds a door, and inside, fauna of various sizes and types, at first all alien. Then he comes across creatures from Earth, and starts to wonder how they got there. He begins to feel nervous, and he gets a feeling that someone is watching him. So he realizes that he shouldn't be there, and makes a hasty return to his ship and takes off.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For instance, is this a prose story, a novel or a film?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153721/need-to-identitify-a-short-story-about-an-astronaut-stranded-alone-on-a-planet-t/153725#153725

Answer (score 10):

["Hobbyist" by Eric Frank Russell](http://adventuresfantastic.com/futurespastandpresent/eric-frank-russells-hobbyist/)

> Steve Ander is flying a Probe Service ship when he gets flung across
> the galaxy.  The important thing is that Steve is
> lost, almost out of fuel, and stranded on a planet

> On the other side of the valley is a giant structure.

> Exploring the structure he
> discovers clear containers containing animals, most unknown to him but
> a few familiar and Terrestrial. Near the back are some machines that
> today would be called 3D printers. They are producing animals,
> although these animals are missing “the breath of life”.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer?

Comment: [Here's a hint](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v40n01_1947-09_cape1736/page/n32/mode/1up)

Comment: Maybe also put something in the answer about the astronaut's bird (a macaw, not a nyna).